# What URL to hit to log out of Facebook through java APIs?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web

I am using the below code to log into Facebook. Once i get the code, using that i get access token and then query graph api and get some basic details.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fblogin")
        public String inititateFBlogin(ModelMap model) {

            System.out.println("in FB login ");

            String fbAuthURL = fbConnectionService.getFBAuthUrl();


            return  "redirect:"+fbAuthURL;

        }


        public String getFBAuthUrl() {
                String fbLoginUrl = "";
                try {
                    fbLoginUrl = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?" + "client_id="
                            + FBConnection.FB_APP_ID + "&redirect_uri="
                            + URLEncoder.encode(FBConnection.REDIRECT_URI, "UTF-8")
                            + "&scope=email";
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return fbLoginUrl;
            }
```

But to logout , i am hitting the URL in below format.
//https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=[YourAppURL]&access_token=[ValidAccessToken]

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fblogout", method=GET)
    public String  fbLogOut(ModelMap model) {


        String fbLogoutURL = "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?confirm=1&next=";


        String appURL = "http://localhost:15005/abc";

        String accessToken = accessTokenFB ;

        String logOutURL =   fbLogoutURL+appURL+"&access_token="+accessToken;

        return "redirect:"+logOutURL;

    }
```

But looks like the above FB url always redirects to the FB homepage.
Is there any way that i can log out by simply calling any FB service through java, I would rather avoid going down to the javascript SDK.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can logout an access token by sending a DELETE (instead of GET/POST) request to /me/permissions

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/permissions/

```
curl -X DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=ABC
```

Comment: Thanks Yuri for the answer :)

Comment: Hi Yuri , I am revoking the permissions of token, but upon log-in second time, the previous user is already present and it simply asks me to continue.
And From FB docs
----
Logging someone out is not the same as revoking login permission (removing previously granted authentication), 
-----

Do I need to do something else, any idea?

Comment: The DELETE will stop that token from working anymore. If you are running inside a mobile app or server on behalf of a user that is what I understood you were trying to do.  I think I'm missing some broader context.

Comment: Hi Yuri,I am logging-in through a web server , Although My DELTE requests is succesfull( http 200), I think permissions are revoked. But log-in second time has somehow the information of that user already and pops upa dialog to  "continue/cancel".

The URL that is use for log-in is
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xyz.........
Is this fine?